# Ant: make "available" throw an understandable error?

Tags: java, ant

When running `ant`, how do I make an `<available />` block throw an adequate error message?

This is what I have so far:

```
<target name="requirements">
  <available classname="foo.bar.baz" property="baz.present" />
</target>

<target name="directories" depends="requirements" if="baz.present">
  <mkdir dir="build" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="directories">
  <!-- build some stuff -->
</target>
```

What I'm currently seeing when `requirements` fails is a message complaining about the ./build dir not being available. How can I change this so that a message is displayed about the missing class, such as "foo.bar.baz is not available"?

Answer (score 3):

How about adding a **fail** to the compile target?

```
<fail message="foo.bar.baz is not available, stopping build!" 
      unless="baz.present"/>
```

This stops the current build with a meaningful error message.
See the Ant documentation of the [**Fail Task**](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html).

Answer (score 1):

The task `<available>` itself does not block, however you can use it in combination with [`<fail>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html).